# Package autoloading and use-package

Tags: use-package, performance, autoload

I'm a beginner on emacs and I don't understand packages autoloading and use-package.
I see a lot of configs online which use 'use-package' and recommends installing packages with package manager (which autoloads them).

So in the end use-package seems useless because package manager does that autoload thing.
Though it seems interesting to use 'use-package' because it's clever.

So:

- Should I disable package autoloading ? How ?
- Should I use 'use-package' with autoloading anyway ? Is autoload off when I use 'use-package'

Also I cannot find good documentation on package autoloading, it seems like magic and It's never really good.